# summing negative elements in list with while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, computer-science

Given a list(in descending order) find the sum of all negative numbers
I was able to solve it with a `for` loop pretty easily:

[image]

But I can't seem to solve it with the `while` loop, and all the solutions I find online are using `len()`, which I haven't learnt yet, is there any other method?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example: do not paste images of code but rather post the code in the question so that people can copy it locally if needed. Good luck!

Comment: @TedKleinBergman this is a new member, I wouldn't rush to downvote but rather default to explaining why is it bad and ask them to correct it.

Comment: @NirAlfasi The link provides a very clear and concise explanation of the issue, which is why I provided it. It's also much more specific then the links to [ask] or [mcve], as it covers the exact issue OP has. It explains how to solve the problem and that OP can message the linker once the issue is resolved for the down vote to be retracted.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman all you wrote is correct and I agree with it and with the intention. The problem with providing a "link-only" comment or answer is when the site goes down or just stopped being maintained. Will a future SO member that will visit here in 5 years, be able to read what's in that link? And if you want to be extra nice: you can add a few encouraging words that will help the OP feel welcomed.

Comment: Using len is best way to go dear. len gives number of items in list. Next time if you see a new function like len, try using help(len) in python terminal.

Comment: @NirAlfasi The comment section is to ask OP for clarity, more information, and suggest improvements. Comments are not necessarily meant to be long-lived, which is why we can flag them as outdated. If the question is edited, the comment will be outdated and the comment should be removed. The comment isn't supposed to be there for several years; it's a 7-days max kind of comment, like the majority of comments on SO. It can't be held to the same standards as a answer. I sometimes write a bit more verbose, encouraging comments but it takes too much time for something that's ignored 95% of the time

Comment: @TedKleinBergman *"It takes too much time for something that's ignored 95% of the time"* 1) They don't get ignored as much as you might think. 2) Encouraging comments don't necessarily take more time than discouraging ones.

Answer (score 2):

you can use list indexes: `l[-1]` would give you the last element of the list and `l[-2]` is the second last element and so on. This idea can be used.As this list is in the descending order you could make sure that the element added to the total is a negative number using `<` condition in the while loop and then break it once the element is found to be positive. let me know if you need more clues/ help! :)

Comment: I would rather not give the code-solution but only describe it and let the OP implement it by themselves.

Comment: what if I briefly explain what I've done first and then add the code? OP can try it and then compare theirs with this one?

Comment: Again, I wouldn't publish the code: this is potentially hurting the OP because it will prevent them from the struggle to write it by themselves and so it'll hurt their effort of learning. Many people are not self disciplined enough to not "peak" at the answers ;)

Comment: edited- I've removed the code and just added the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

As in question list is sorted in descending order. You can start with last element and loop till you found element which is equal to or greater then `0` and break the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

With the suggested negative index solution, along with the give input example, we need to consider other cases: empty list; all positive list; all negative list.  Short of adding a `try` clause, we can deal with all of them by forcing an end token onto the front of the tested list:

```
given_list4 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]

total7 = 0
index = -1

while [0, *given_list4][index] < 0:
    total7 += given_list4[index]
    index -= 1

print(total7)
```

Clearly, a `try` clause would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative indices:

```
given_list4 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]

total7 = 0
index = -1

while given_list4[index] < 0:
    total7 += given_list4[index]
    index -= 1

print(total7)
```

Output:

```
-17
```

The `-1` index of an array is the last element of the array, `-2` is the second-last, `-3` is the third last, and so on.

Note that this only works if there is at least one number in the list that is not negative, or else it will throw an index error. To avoid the index error, you can add

```
given_list4 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]

if given_list4[0] >= 0:
    total7 = 0
    index = -1
    while given_list4[index] < 0:
        total7 += given_list4[index]
        index -= 1
else:
    total7 = sum(given_list4)
```

This also assumes that the list is not empty. If the list may be empty, another `if` statement would be needed:

```
given_list4 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]
if given_list4:
    if given_list4[0] >= 0:
        total7 = 0
        index = -1
        while given_list4[index] < 0:
            total7 += given_list4[index]
            index -= 1
    else:
        total7 = sum(given_list4)
```

Comment: Neither your second nor third example run -- the both throw errors.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! What does an index of -1 indicate? (i know an index of 0 indicates the first variable of the list, what happens with -1?)

Comment: @psaras The `-1` index of an array is the last element of the array, `-2` is the second-last, `-3` is the third last, and so on.